# Can't resolve ip when running inside visualstudio 2022 debugger

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

As of this morning, when hitting F5 and running any debug app or service inside the debugger I cannot resolve any IP addresses. This includes multiple types of requests, AMQP, Http, etc.

If I run the same apps (even debug builds) directly they work absolutely fine. Has anyone experienced this before and got the solution?

Have tried the obvious cleaning, rebuilding, rebooting, restarting router and modem.

Comment: Firewall problem? Firewall rules?

Comment: I don't see how it could have changed while I was asleep and the PC was off. Just completely cleared my disk down of all projects, same issue. Have loaded the code on another machine, debugs fine. Next step is total re-install of visual studio. What a waste of time.

Comment: Have you had a look at the firewall rules? They might not have changed while you where sleeping, but they might have changed as soon as you switched your PC back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end it took a complete uninstall of visual studio. I also took the time to clean up my disk, install latest updates, update .NET6 and clear all repos.

I don't know if the issue was the resolution of IPs or whether that was a symptom of something else. I was getting a large number of exceptions and being taken to the screen about missing pdbs constantly.

Either way, the issue has now gone away and I'm debugging again.