# SQL Connection Error 0 — if I start my Program from Visual Studio. It works from the build executable if started separately

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0, sqlconnection

I am building an Windows Forms App an can not connect to my SQL Server from within Visual Studio. If I build the app and start it separately from the folder, connection is instantly established and communication with the Server works. Then I can read/write/delete sucessfully.
If I start/run the Aplication from within Visual Studio I cannot talk with the SQL Server.
In the Debugger Output I get an Exception:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.SqlClient.dll

After the connection timeout I get an error.

> ...(provider: TCP, error: 0 - on Database call an not resolvable error
> occured) [my translation from german]

The Server listens on a non standard Port (30500), in the meantime I switched to 1433 and back and nothing is working, from within the IDE.

I Use:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (x64) with nonAdmin Domain
> Account.  Version 17.8.5 VisualStudio.17.Release/17.8.5+34511.84
> Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.04084 Installierte Version:
> Community
>
> Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA825
>  Microsoft Visual C++
> 2022
>  ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.8.358.6298
>  ASP.NET and Web
> Tools
>  Azure App Service-Tools v3.0.0   17.8.358.6298
>  Azure
> App Service-Tools v3.0.0
>  C#-Tools
> 4.8.0-7.23572.1+7b75981cf3bd520b86ec4ed00ec156c8bc48e4eb
>  Common Azure Tools   1.10
>  Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
> NuGet-Paket-Manager   6.8.0
>  SQL Server Data Tools
> 17.8.120.1
>  Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>  SQLite & SQL Server Compact Toolbox   4.8
>  TypeScript-Tools
> 17.0.20920.2001
>  TypeScript-Tools für Microsoft Visual Studio
>  Visual Basic-Tools
> 4.8.0-7.23572.1+7b75981cf3bd520b86ec4ed00ec156c8bc48e4eb
>  Microsoft Visual F# Tools
>  Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
> KI-gestützte Entwicklung für Visual Studio.

MyCode is essentialy just creating the connection string, placing it into the connection object and (trying to) open connection.

```
Public Const strDBSource As String = "Data Source=Computername,30501\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=xxx_DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"

''alternative

Private connectionString_FuEDB As String = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder With {.DataSource = "TTS-NB-LABOR,30501", '"192.168.13.62,30501\SQLEXPRESS",
                                                                          .InitialCatalog = "FXXxxx_DB",
                                                                          .UserID = "xxx",
                                                                          .Password = "xxx",
                                                                          .TrustServerCertificate = True}.ConnectionString

[...]

 sqlCon = New SqlClient.SqlConnection
 sqlCon.ConnectionString = strDBSource
 'sqlCon.ConnectionString = connectionString_FuEDB

[...]

Try
   If sqlCon.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
      Debug.WriteLine("State: not (jet) Open, trying to open..")
      sqlCon.Open()
[...]
End Try`
```

As the connection works with the (release) build, I assume there isn't something essential wrong from the code point of view.

I can connect from SQL Mgmt Studio, I can connect via an .udl test connection. I cann connect via the VS integrated SQL Server Explorer. I cann not connect from my App.

I tried various connection-strings at first. They all failed. After some time I tried to connect to an other SQL server where I have the connectionString and also an working method, to try to establishing an connection. This also failed. Then I build the damn thing and started it from explorer and connection succeeded!

I tried NamedPipes, but same error, also I did not invest to much time into it. It may had connectionString issues as well.

I made sure all ports are open on the Serverside. As connection is working from the build, I think it works.

Somewhere on the way I made an new application just for connection-testing. Doesen't work from the IDE (in Debug mode). From this application I tested a lot of variations of connectionStrings, most of them worked. Some where just plain wrong. Non of them work from within the IDE.

I came accross an MS Article which stated that port 135 TCP should be open for Visual Studio and SQL ManagementStudio, the are open. In fact for testing I opend all Port for thode two aplications.

Any Ideas what else I can try?

**Update**
I saw I can start the Programm without Debugging. Then it is working.
I edited the debug mode. Enabled and disabled Hot Reload and SQL-Server-Debugging. Same result, not working in Debug mode.

**2nd Update**
As proposed by @HardCode I post the whole connection Section from my code:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.Common
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

Public Class Hauptfenster

[..some other variable declarations.]


    Public Const strDBSource As String = "Data Source =Name-OfDevice-LABOR,30xxx;Database=xxx_DB;User ID=SA;Password=sa;"
   'Public Const strDBSource As String = "Data Source=Name-OfDevice-LABOR,30xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx_DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SA;Password=sa;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"
   Private connectionString_xxxDB As String = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder With {.DataSource = "Name-OfDevice-LABOR,30xxx1", '"192.168.local.ip,30xxx",
                                                                             .InitialCatalog = "xxx_DB",
                                                                             .UserID = "SA",
                                                                             .Password = "sa",
                                                                             .TrustServerCertificate = True}.ConnectionString
   Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection
   Dim sqlQuerry As SqlCommand
   Private Sub openConnection()

      If IsNothing(sqlCon) Then
         sqlCon = New SqlClient.SqlConnection
         sqlCon.ConnectionString = strDBSource
         'sqlCon.ConnectionString = connectionString_xxxDB
      End If

      Ausgabe_Log(String.Format("ConnectionString: {0}", sqlCon.ConnectionString))
      Ausgabe_Log(String.Format("State_: {0}", sqlCon.State))

      Try
         If sqlCon.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            Debug.WriteLine("State: not (jet) Open, trying to open")
            sqlCon.Open()
            Ausgabe_Log(String.Format("Resultat nach Verbindugnsversuch: {0}", sqlCon.State))
         End If
      Catch sqlexception As SqlClient.SqlException
         MsgBox(sqlexception.Message)
         Ausgabe_Log(String.Format("SQL-Fehler: {0}", sqlexception.Message))
         Debug.WriteLine(sqlexception.Message)
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
         Ausgabe_Log(String.Format("Allg. Fehler: {0}", ex.Message))
         Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
      End Try
```

The Exception is happening at :

```vb
 sqlCon.Open()
```

I tried to trace the source of the Error and am qurrently stuck somewhere in "DbConnectionPools.cs"  in TryGetConnection(...).
There is an condition check dbConnectionInternal == null. It enters this path. dbConnectionInternal = UserCreateRequest(owningObject, userOptions); faisll.

I am getting an Win32Exception on a Win 10 Pro - x64 System. This is wondering me a litte bit. The SQL Server is running on a x32-System so this is maybe related? I just caught my eye and I just want to mention it.

**Update 3** (2024-02-12)
I Implemented the whole communication with EF-Core. I Still can not get any SQL Connection in Debug-Mode.

I recreated the whole Project in vb.net7 from a clean Projectfile. Just copied the, the few files with written code. And installed all packages for .net7 again. Same Result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294721/how-to-specify-a-port-number-in-sql-server-connection-string You don't need both the port and the instance name, as each instance is on a different port already.

Comment: You may consider re-evaluating your connection string. The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199793/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794540/10024425

Comment: @HardCode, tried it without port and without instance name. Still got connection error. Can the connection string be wrong, if I succeed to connect in not Debug-Mode

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* your connection string works from the compiled .exe? Do you have an empty Catch statement (your code is abbreviated)? Maybe show your entire code block.

Comment: @HardCode i pasted my code. I am sure the string in the compiled .exe works. Because i get live response from the Server. I can change a Dataset in the DB. I can read the Dataset in the Programm.

Comment: I tried and searched some more.. The trace of the error in the 2nd Update pointed me to some "DNS problems". Then I recognized I can't nslookup/ping any Name in Debug Mode. I can ping IP-Adresses though. In Release it works. I found this question with some unpleasant solution. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70566428/cant-resolve-ip-when-running-inside-visualstudio-2022-debugger) .Will Try later wenn out Admins are inhouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I relocated the Project to a local Drive. Away from "User-Networkdrive" which is the default Userfolder, as we get it assigned per Domain-Settings.

I started to get perfomance Problems and was wondering why. Recognized that the Data are not localy stored.
After moving Project to local drive I thought why not try Debuging again. It worked.

I still have ocasionaly some timing issues which result in Exceptions. But the essential Problem of not getting an Connection in Debug-Mode is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

***This is not an answer. This is too many recommendations for comments, and it will be deleted once communicated to the OP.***

You have a lot of "fluff" and bad practices around your use of database connections. You are trying to open a connection and doing nothing with it. You have `If` statements that will always return true due to the nature of how the `SqlConnection` object works. For example, you are declaring an SqlConnection object and then immediately are checking if it is open. It will *never* be open until you open it. That's unnecessary "fluff" that just distracts from actual issues, like your connection string issue.

Also, Hungarian Notation is long dead :-).

Here is how you should structure your code. Notice I'm doing away with an `OpenConnection` Sub, because you never open a connection to the database until you are about to run a query. I'm also declaring the SqlClient objects with `Using`, so they are properly and automatically disposed. Use `Using` with anything that implements `IDisposable`.

```
Public Class Hauptfenster

Public Const _connectionString As String = "Data Source =Name-OfDevice-LABOR,30xxx;Database=xxx_DB;User ID=SA;Password=sa;"

Private Sub ReadMyData()

    ' Add in your logging and error handling around this code structure.
    ' No need to constantly check the connection state. You'll get an exception thrown
    ' if you try to use a connection that isn't open.

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(_connectionString)

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Foo", conn)

            conn.Open()

            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)

            ' Use DataTable dt to populate the data on your form. Like a DataGridView, for example.
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        End Using

    End Using
End Sub

End Class
```

Now, there is a lot less unnecessary code for debugging.

Comment: Thank you @HardCode. Looks a Loot cleaner.